# Read .svg file from server in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, xmlhttprequest

I am working on svg and javascript. I want to read and display svg in html, svg is placed on my localhost and html is on another computer's localhost. Both are connected in LAN. I want to get svg file in javascript i try a lot but not success my code is as follows

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/SVG/svg1.svg",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

it generates an error like this:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost/SVG/svg1.svg No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.118' is therefore not allowed access.
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/SVG/svg1.svg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.118' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way this will work is that in lieu of `http://localhost/SVG/svg1.svg` you determine the relative address of the

```
../SVG/svg1.svg
```

Comment: its not work because my svg folder and html folder both are on different server, if same server than not any issue.